# Возможна ли генерация кода в процессе работы?

Tags: ассемблер, reverse-engineering

Здравствуйте.
Исследуя одну прошивку я наткнулся на такую структуру:

```
.data:832FF940 .word aAddiu # "addiu"  
.data:832FF944 .word 0x24000000  
.data:832FF948 .word 0xFC000000  
.data:832FF94C .word aRtRsI # "rt,rs,i"  
.data:832FF950 .word 0  
.data:832FF954 .word aSlti # "slti"  
.data:832FF958 .word 0x28000000  
.data:832FF95C .word 0xFC000000  
.data:832FF960 .word aRtRsI # "rt,rs,i"  
.data:832FF964 .word 0
```

Сначала идёт мнемоника, потом код команды, маска (первые 6 бит op-code команды), формат команды, 0 - признак окончания.
И так хранятся все инструкции процессора.
Вот я подумал может ли быть такое, что потом по этим данным будет строится исполняемый код в процессе работы?
Для чего вообще может понадобиться хранить эти данные в прошивке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего это нужно для отладки отладочного вывода (например, вывода кода, в котором произошел краш, или что-то вроде этого).

Для генерации кода не нужно хранить имена команд и их операндов, маска также нужна для выделения опкода, но не нужна при генерации команды. Для генерации кода также не нужен полный набор команд процессора, если это конечно не компилятор/ассемблер.

Вряд ли за счет генерации кода можно что-то выиграть, наоборот, скорее всего получится перерасход ресурсов.

Читал, что за счет самомодифицируемого кода можно было выиграть в размере программы (какие-нибудь дополнительные байты), но сам не пробовал. Но опять же, полный набор команд тут не нужен.

Answer (score 0):

Надо смотреть по коду как потом используются эти переменные.

Как варианты:

1. Для отладки
2. Для упрощения генерации кода. Как правило у МП объем памяти кода был меньше чем объем памяти данных. И таким образом можно "объять необъятное"

Comment: Не очень понял "Для упрощения генерации кода", не могли бы вы пояснить.

Comment: @Alex при генерации кода можно его писать прямо в кодах. Т.е. положить в область памяти кусок кода, при необходимости копировать его в область кода и передавать туда выполнение. Но в кодах аоддерживать это муторно. Если нет проблем с памятью, то можно записать в память некоторый справочник, вида "команда - код". А сам код писать в виде списка команд. А генератор кода, проходится по списку, берет из справочника код для каждой команды и формирует уже собственно код. Ну это только домыслы - я бы так сделал, будь у меня такая задача и при отсутствии ограничений по памяти.

Comment: @newman, можно, например, коды обернуть в макросы, тогда все будет более-менее понятно и поддерживаемо. И дополнительных накладных расходов на хранение ассемблерного кода и собственно ассемблера не будет.

Comment: @insolor сделать можно что угодно. Теоретически рассуждать можно как угодно. Как это на практике реализовал конкретный разработчик - это его выбор и его право.

Comment: @newman, согласен. Нужно смотреть как эта таблица из вопроса используется, тогда возможно станет понятнее для чего она.